# Calling a web-service dynamically using WSDL

Tags: web-services, apache-camel

I need to configure the camel route endpoint using WSDL file.

I don't know the service classes and I don't want to put the service class files in my class path. I have only the WSDL file.

How can I solve my task ?

Answer (score 0):

Define the camel cxf endpoint as follows

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="testServiceEndpoint" address="http://localhost:9000/web-service/TestService" wsdlURL="TestService.wsdl" serviceClass="com.webservice.AllServiceService" endpointName="s:TestServiceHttpSoap11Endpoint" serviceName="s:TestPutService" xmlns:s="http://webservices/testService"/>
```

Route configuration

```
<route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:testServiceEndpoint"/>
<to uri="log:output?showAll=true" />
</route>
```

Note that I have mentioned a serviceClass attribute, but this class can be made generic to handle all webservices by using **@WebServiceProvider** annotation

```
@WebServiceProvider
@ServiceMode(Mode.PAYLOAD)
public class AllServiceService implements Provider<StreamSource> {

    @Override
    public StreamSource invoke(StreamSource request) {
    }
}
```